# Is there any uniform date for applying for Phd positions in the Italy for mathematics?

Tags: phd, mathematics, europe, italy

I am not a resident of Europe and I am in 2nd year of my masters in Mathematics.

My research interest aligns with many professors of universities in Italy. I wrote to one prof. asking about open position for PhD but he said normally application window is open in December -January. I was under the impression that it Italy the application window is from June to July (I saw some ads during my 1st year and that's why I thought of this).

Can you please confirm about approximate months of application window in Italy for mathematics?

Comment: It depends on the institutions. Since you are from outside Europe, you should consider applying to the SISSA doctoral school in Trieste. Great school, english speaking administration, great connections to many places in Europe and the US ... and the city is a wonderful city lying on the sea (but you have also fog in autumn and cold and snow in winter, so you can enjoy all seasons).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't really a uniform application window for the PhD in Italy, and every university has its own deadlines (e.g. my university has three application windows with deadlines in February, June and September).

Even though December-January seems a bit unusual, I wouldn't exclude this possibility. Since universities have websites in which the PhD application deadlines are advertised, I suggest you to have a look at the one of that university, also because deadlines may change across years and professors may not be aware of the changes (don't trust professors on deadlines!).

Comment: Maybe an important point to add is that PhD positions in Italy are given out at the department level, and then the students decide who they want to work with. In other countries it's professors that hire their own students.